# 0-1 roots in a free algebra

Tags: polynomials, algebras

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and consider the free algebra $\mathbb{F}\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n \rangle $, that is, the algebra of non-commutative polynomials with coefficients from $\mathbb{F}$. Let $p\in\mathbb{F}\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n \rangle $.

**Question**: Is it possible that there exist two $\mathbb{F}$-algebras $A_0$ and $A_1$ and an assignment $b\in\{0,1\}^n$ of $0,1$ values (the zero and unit elements in $A_0$ and in $A_1$, respectively) to the $x_i$ variables such that $p(b)=0$ when computed in $A_0$ but $p(b)\neq 0$ when computed in $A_1$?

Comment: What about $A_1=\Bbb{F}<x>$ and $A2=\Bbb{F}<x>/x\Bbb{F}<x>$, with $p(x)=x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $\mathbb{F}$-algebra $A$ the evaluation map $\mathbb{F}\langle x_1,\dots,x_n \rangle \rightarrow A$ at $b$ factors through $\mathbb{F} \rightarrow A$ because $b \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$ by your assumption, that is, it is the composition of the evaluation map $\mathbb{F}\langle x_1,\dots,x_n \rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ with the canonoical map $\mathbb{F} \rightarrow A$. Hence $p(b)$ is computed in $A$ by computing it in $\mathbb{F}$ and taking the image under $\mathbb{F} \rightarrow A$ which is an injection. So $p(b) = 0$ in $A$ if and only if this is the case in $\mathbb{F}$ and so this identity is independent of the choice of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, note that $b\not\in\mathbb{F}^n$, because the zero and unit elements are in $A_0, A_1$ respectively (e.g.,  zero and unit matrices).

Comment: You are right that it is not really the zero and unit of $\mathbb{F}$, however, the field $\mathbb{F}$ embeds into every $\mathbb{F}$-algebra $A$ (mapping $a \in \mathbb{F}$ to $a \cdot 1$) and as this is an injective homomorphism of $\mathbb{F}$-algebras it allows us to identify $\mathbb{F}$ with its image in $A$ and under this identification the zero and unit of $A$ become the zero and unit of $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Note also that because, as you say 0,1 in any $\mathbb{F}$-algebra can be identified with 0,1 in $\mathbb{F}$ then a negative answer to my question follows immediately: the value of $p(b)$ is simply the corresponding sum of $1$'s (since the assignment is 0,1 and so every monomial is either 0 or 1), and this sum must be the same in $A_0$ and $A_1$.

Comment: You are right, that was exactly what I meant.